# Cauchy-Schwarz and changing spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

[A statistical paper](http://math.uni-heidelberg.de/studinfo/reiss/Publikationen/GalInvProb.pdf) I am studying states the following

$$ \|g\|_{L^2} = \sup_{f \in L^2 \; \text{and}\; \|f\| = 1} | \langle g, f \rangle |
_{L^2} \;\leq\; C\; \|g\|_{H^{-\frac{t}{2}}} \|f\|_{H^{\frac{t}{2}}}$$

where $C$ is a constant and $H^{\pm\frac{t}{2}}$ are Sobolev space $W^{\frac{t}{2}, 2}$ and its dual. As far as I can see, $t$ is left unspecified but positive.

Maybe I am missing something but the inequality seems to be some kind of Cauchy-Schwarz allowing to change the space where inner product is taken. Is that obvious from some known result?

By the way, $g$ and $f$ also live in a wavelet space and the inequality could potentially depend on that...

Comment: Please let me know if I can somehow improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the notation of the paper, $g_j$ is not an arbitrary $L^2$-function, but $g_j \in V_j$, where $V_j$ is a closed subspace of $L^2$. Hence, you have to take the $\sup$ only over $f_j \in V_j$. But for those $f_j$ you have
$$\|f_j\|_{L^2} \le C_j \, \|f_j\|_{H^{t/2}},$$where $C_j$ depends on $j$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I still fail to see how you make appear $\|g_{j}\|_{H^{-t/2}} = \sup \langle g_{j}, \cdot \rangle_{H^{t/2}}$ whereas the initial inner product is taken in $L^{2}$. Could you please add more details for clarification?

Comment: This is due to the hiding of the embedding $I : H^{t/2} \ to L^2$ (and its adjoint $I^* : L^2 \to H^{-t/2}$. If you have $g \in L^2$ and $f \in H^{t/2}$, you get $$(g,I\,f)_{L^2} = (I^*\,g,f)_{H^{-t/2},H^{t/2}}.$$Removing the $I$ and $I^*$ on both sides, you get your identity.

Comment: Thank you! I suggest to put the latter directly in the answer to make it complete. You saved my day!